# TikZ random messes with coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw random points in a polar coordinate system with lines leading down to a circle. This is absolutely straightforward, but the result is not as expected.  There seems to be an interference between the random functions provided by Ti*k*Z and the polar system.

Under XeLaTeX, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \myangle in {0, 20, ..., 340} {
    \draw (\myangle:{random(0.5, 2)}) -- (\myangle:1);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \myangle in {0, 20, ..., 340} {
    \draw (\myangle:{2*rnd + 0.5}) -- (\myangle:1);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: Because I use XeLaTeX for the remainder of the text. In past problems, I found that XeLaTeX does not have smooth support for tikz, hence the additional information.

Comment: `random(x ,y )` generates a random **integer**, see p. 1009 of the pgfmanual. You cannot use a noninteger for `x` if you use more than one variable.

Comment: @marmot good observation, but that doesn't explain the behaviour that the lines do not radiate outwards as expected from polar coordinates

Comment: Yes, because there is an additional expansion issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I admit that this is somewhat confusing. There are two issues here:

- integer vs. noninteger;
- expansion.

As for the first issue, `random`, when used with two arguments, expects these arguments to be integers. It then returns an integer. If you do not use arguments, it returns a real number between `0` and `1`. This is described in detail on pages 1008-1009 of the pgfmanual. Once you feed it with a noninteger it doesn't know what to do and just returns the noninteger, i.e. `0.5` in this case. This issue is not related to `xelatex`, but `pdflatex` yields the same output. I believe you are looking for `{1.5*random() + 0.5}` (or `{1.5*rnd + 0.5}`).

And then there are expansion issue. I believe I had an answer on this one somewhere, but do not remember where. Basically, you have to force Ti*k*Z to pin down the random number rather than leaving it random.

The following code resolves these issues.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1);
\foreach \myangle in {0, 20, ..., 340} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{1.5*random() + 0.5}
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw (\myangle:\myrnd) -- (\myangle:1);}
    \temp
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wonderful, that resolves it.